# Does order stays the same after dividing up dataframe and merge again?

Tags: r

I started with a data frame with about 20'000 observations and around 200 columns. Since its a survey I divided the columns up in around 6 sections. I did some calculations like select columns == "something", changed 0 to NA etc.

I did no sorting or oder columns by a value. In the end I am gonna merge the dataframes again with cbind. Can I be sure that the order is still the same? Is it somehow possible to fix the order within a dataframe?

Comment: "I did no sorting or o[r]der columns by a value." If you didn't do that (implicitly nor explicitly), the order won't have changed.

Comment: To be sure you could create a helper column. Something like: `DF$index <- seq_len(nrow(DF))`